# How to fetch the data from one API store into state and then pass this data into another API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

```js
class myFetchData extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data : [],
            Issuer_News : []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({loading : true})

        axios.post('https://bqskvn9laah.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dev/datalist',{
            DATA: this.state.data
          }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({data : res, number_of_data : response.data[1].total_data_issued_by_the_company,loading : false})})
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        fetch(`https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=${this.state.data.Issuer_Name}&max=5&token=52498bb02769e98d131156c2648628ca`)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({Issuer_News : data.articles}))
}
```

I want data from API 1 and to pass the data from API 1 to API 2 but `this.state.data` returns `undefined`.

Comment: API call is async as well as setState .it will not wait for call to complete and make the second API call. You should make the second call in .then block

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS, both setState and fetch function is asynchronous so this is why you got undefined. Because the API 2 could run before the success promise of API 1 is returned. I prefer to call the fetch function of API 2 in the success promise. Like this

```
    axios.post('https://bqskvn9laah.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dev/datalist',{
        DATA: this.state.data
      }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({data : res, number_of_data : 
     response.data[1].total_data_issued_by_the_company,loading : false})
      fetch(`https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=${response.data.Issuer_Name}&max=5&token=52498bb02769e98d131156c2648628ca`)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({Issuer_News : data.articles}))
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I would recommend you to use some state manager library like redux, redux-saga to control your flow of api call more easily

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you want to chain the api calls, you will need to call the second api in the setState method of then() block of first api where you receive the data. [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method has one variant in which you can pass a function as argument and it ensures that that is run only when the setState has been called.

Only making calls in the then() block would not suffice if you are using `this.state.data`. You need to put the fetch call in the setState's callback function. If you don't want to use the callback function variant, then just use the response variable directly in the then() method.

Assuming `axios.post` is the first API and `fetch` is the second

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading : true})

    axios.post('<yourUrl>', {
        ...
      }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({<setYourState>}, () => {
           fetch(`https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=${this.state.data.Issuer_Name}&max=5&token=52498bb02769e98d131156c2648628ca`)
               .then( response => response.json())
               .then(data => this.setState({Issuer_News : data.articles}))
}
        })
})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```